# JCR-SQL - contains function doesn't escape special characters?

Tags: lucene, aem, jcr, jcr-sql2

I have the following query string:

`SELECT jcr:title, jcr:created, jcr:description FROM cq:PageContent WHERE jcr:path LIKE '/content/.../%' AND CONTAINS (., '*') ORDER BY date ASC`

The problem is that the query is returning all nodes from the given path even though they don't have asterisk in any proeprty. I wanted to escape the asterisk character, but the result is the same. I've tried something like this:

`SELECT jcr:title, jcr:created, jcr:description FROM cq:PageContent WHERE jcr:path LIKE '/content/.../%' AND CONTAINS (., '\*') ORDER BY date ASC`

or even something like this:

`SELECT jcr:title, jcr:created, jcr:description FROM cq:PageContent WHERE jcr:path LIKE '/content/.../%' AND CONTAINS (., '\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*') ORDER BY date ASC`

In all these queries, the result is the same, even though none of these pages have property which contains the asterisk character (or 11 of them)

The [documentation of jcr:contains function](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jcr/1.0/6.6.5.2_jcr_contains_Function.html) says:

> Within the searchexp literal instances of single quote (“'”), double quote (“"”) and hyphen (“-”) must be escaped with a backslash (“\”). Backslash itself must therefore also be escaped, ending up as double backslash (“\”).

Other characters like `*` are not mentioned so it should work even without any escaping (?). Please let me understand why I'm getting such results here and how to properly escape such chars.

Comment: Please include some matching and non matching sample data.  By the way, I think most folks here are not familiar with your flavor of SQL.

Comment: What AEM version are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, if `jcr:contains` is the right method for you. Maybe `jcr:like` is the better approach for what you want.

`jcr:contains` is a fulltext search, and uses a lucene index. So it might have some unexpected impacts. It also cannot so easily combined with other indexes.

`jcr:like` is a attribute comparison with wildcards. And this wildcards can be escaped with a backslash. (https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jcr/1.0/6.6.5.1_jcr_like_Function.html)

---

**1st Example SQL-2 Query**

Searches cq:PageContent nodes with an * in any attribute. The % (percent-sign) is the wildcard-symbol. The * is searched.

```
SELECT * FROM [cq:PageContent] AS content
WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/myproject/...')
AND content.* LIKE '%*%'
```

---

**2nd Example SQL-2 Query**

Searches cq:PageContent nodes with an % in any attribute. Therefore the percent-sign is escaped with \% (and surrounded by the wildcard %).

```
SELECT * FROM [cq:PageContent] AS content
WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/myproject/...')
AND content.* LIKE '%\%%'
```

---

**3rd Example XPath Query**

Almost the same as the last one, just as XPath query. Only I just don't know, how you can search for any attribute. So this example searches for jcr:title attributes.

```
/jcr:root/content/myproject/...//element(*, cq:PageContent)[jcr:like(@jcr:title, '%\%%')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Th documentation you put in has the answer. There are special characters that you have to escape, however if you want something literal such as the asterisk to match only the the character ‘*’ then you have to use the escape character which is a backslash. What the documentation states that is a bit confusing is that the backslash itself is a special character when parsing a string, so if you want the backslash to be seen as an escape character you need to escape it.

In other words, to escape the asterisk you need to write it as

```
\\*
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the answer on [Jackrabbit Wiki page](https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/EncodingAndEscaping)

> ### Escaping text in fulltext (contains) clauses
>
> Jackrabbit Oak uses the [Apache Lucene grammar for fulltext search](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html). So to escape user-supplied text for use in contains, you will need to either filter out all the special characters, or escape them. So for example, to filter out the special characters, use:
>
> `String filteredContains = searchTerm.replaceAll("[\\Q+-&|!(){}[]^\"~*?:\\/\\E]", "");
>   String q =
>     "/jcr:root/foo/element(*, foo)" +
>     "[jcr:contains(@title, '" + filteredContains.replaceAll("'", "''") + "')]" +
>     "[@itemID = '" + itemID.replaceAll("'", "''") + "']";`
>
> Only for Jackrabbit 2.x: use `Text.escapeIllegalXpathSearchChars(...)` for calls to jcr:contains(...) (see also JCR-1248):
>
> `String q =
>     "/jcr:root/foo/element(*, foo)" +
>     "[jcr:contains(@title, '" + Text.escapeIllegalXpathSearchChars(searchTerm).replaceAll("'", "''") + "')]" +
>     "[@itemID = '" + itemID.replaceAll("'", "''") + "']";`