# XPath contains() not working

Tags: xml, xpath, aem, jcr

We are trying to get all the nodes containing a property value starting from below string `"/content/retail/mx/mexico/es/"` . For this we have written a AEM XPath query:

```
/jcr:root/content/retail/mx/mexico//* 
[
jcr:contains(., '/content/retail/mx/mexico/es/' ) 
]
```

We are getting the results but problem is we are getting results of those nodes also who contains property value `"/content/retail/mx/mexico/es_mexico"`. It seems XPath doesn't consider the last `"/"` in path.

Is there anyway to escape so that we don't get the results of nodes having `es_mexico`?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question. I think you also better go with jcr:like. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694248/jcr-sql-contains-function-doesnt-escape-special-characters/49798681#49798681

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JCR-SQL - contains function doesn't escape special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694248/jcr-sql-contains-function-doesnt-escape-special-characters)

Answer (score 1):

Normally in XPath, `contains()` tests for ***substring containment***.

If you want ***string equality*** instead, use the `=` equality operator with the strings as arguments.

Furthermore, your XPath,

```
/jcr:root/content/retail/mx/mexico//* 
[
jcr:contains(., '/content/retail/mx/mexico/es/' ) 
]
```

has a number of notable aspects:

1. You're using a special `jcr:contains()` function rather than the XPath `contains()`.   Why?
2. You're testing the string value `.` of all elements `//*` beneath `/jcr:root/content/retail/mx/mexico/`.  This will likely result in several selections of ancestor elements in addition to child elements – perhaps not what you expect.
3. You're testing string content against an XPath-like literal string.  Why?